# PHP/Laravel, what's the purpose of "function with($obj){return $obj;}"??? Chaining? How?

Tags: php, oop, laravel, chaining

In Laravel, which is quite clever, they have a "helper" function "with":

```
function with($object){return $object;}
```

It's not a method, it's a stand-alone function. They claim it has something to do with chaining - is it compensating for some weird deficiency in PHP syntax where you can build an object or an expression in the argument to the function, but can't apply a method or operate on the result until you return it?

That's what I'm finally starting to suspect as I write this, but that's so weird I wonder if it's something else altogether that I'm missing.

Thanks - it's just been bothering me for years! I can't see why you would have to return an object from a function to chain it to another...

Answer (score 0):

I would assume for the most part because `(new Blah)->method()` (Class member access on instantiation) wasn't added until PHP version 5.4.